# SQL Server XML Type Select Where Attribute = X From Any Tag

Tags: sql-server, xpath, xquery-sql

```
select *
from tablename
where CONVERT(xml, Sections).value('(/sections/section/@value)[1]', 'varchar(1)') = 'f'
```

will properly retrieve a record with the following value in the Sections column:

```
<sections><section value="f" priority="4" /><section value="a" priority="4" /></sections>
```

But misses this:

```
<sections><section value="w" priority="4" /><section value="f" priority="4" /></sections>
```

Obviously this is the problem "`/sections/section/@value)[1]`" but I don't understand the syntax and Google hasn't been too helpful.  I found some code that got me this far, but I don't know how to modify it so that it will look through all  tags instead of just the first one.  I tried dropping the `[1]` but that gave the following error:

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [exist()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx).

```
select *
from tablename
where CONVERT(xml, Sections).exist('/sections/section[@value = "f"]') = 1
```

If you want to use some dynamic value instead a hard coded `f` in the query you can use [sql:variable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx).

```
declare @Value varchar(10) = 'f'

select *
from tablename
where CONVERT(xml, Sections).exist('/sections/section[@value = sql:variable("@Value")]') = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the link do the documentation too.  My Google Fu is weak today but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple entries of an XML tag, you need to use the `.nodes()` XQuery method:

```
select 
    *,
    Sections(Section).value('(@value)[1]', 'varchar(1)') 
from tablename
cross apply CONVERT(xml, Sections).nodes('/sections/section') AS Sections(Section)
```

With this, you create a "pseudo-table" called `Sections(Section)` that contains one XML row for each element that matches your XPath (for each `<section>` under `<sections>`). You can then reach into this pseudo-table and extract individual bits of information from those XML "rows" using hte usual `.value()` method